# asp.net mvc Error occurred during a cryptographic operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

i read a lot of topics regarding the issue "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation" but i still did not find a solution for my problem.
In nearly all cases the people say "add a static machinekey in the web.config". I did that but i still have this issue.
My Setup:

I have a ASP.NET MVC Application with Azure AD Authentification which runs in Azure on two Virtual Machines. On these Virtual Machines is also another ASP.NET Application running which works totally fine.
I use RedisCache for Sessionmanagment.

I created the machineKey in IIS and then i added it like this in the web.config:

```
<machineKey  compatibilityMode="Framework45" decryptionKey="DEC-KEY"
           validationKey="VAL-KEY" />
```

This is of course in each web.config of the two servers.

The problem now is i clear all my browsercache and cookies and call my Application and then i log in with my Microsoft Account and immediately after the successfull login i get the error.
I do not see my application once.

Local everything is working fine.

Does anybody has an idea what i'm missing?
Thanks for your help in adavance!

**UPDATE:** Here is my current web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>    

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="DB-SOURCE" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="../logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="CLIENTID" />
    <add key="AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="CLIENTSECRET" />
    <add key="Domain" value="DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="TenantId" value="TENANTID" />
    <add key="PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://DOMAIN.com" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    Eine Beschreibung der Änderungen von 'web.config' finden Sie unter 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367'.

    Die folgenden Attribute können für das <httpRuntime>-Tag festgelegt werden.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->


  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <machineKey validationKey="VAL_KEY" decryptionKey="DEC_KEY" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateStore" timeout="20">
      <providers>
        <add name="RedisSessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="REDIS-HOST" accessKey="REDIS-KEY" ssl="true" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Core" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.9.3.19379" newVersion="1.9.3.19379" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.PlatformServices" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.9.2.27818" newVersion="1.9.2.27818" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:5 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Best Regards,
Metabolic

Comment: Having had some issues with AD in the past - can you please: 1. Clear your cookies again. 2. Login to microsoft online (without going to your application). 3.Logout. Attempt to visit your application again.

Comment: hmm, no this did not work. i still get the exception

Comment: did you implement the AAD Auth. or used the Azure Web App Auth config?  Having same machine key is only one part of the solution. Second part is to replace the default DPAPI crypto service provider for the cookie encryption. Can you paste your web.config here. Most important parts are `system.webserver`, `system.identitymodel` and `system.identitymodel.services`.

Comment: i also added <system.identityModel> to the web.config. is there anything else needed?